# Vues js не видит запрос laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Я создал контроллер, модель, прописал маршрут в api.php, с помощью vue js я вызываю функцию в контроллере, но в консоль vue выводит это "Не удалось загрузить Fetch: POST (http://brainapi/api/devices/light/1)"
Вот путь прописанный в api.php

```
Route::post('/devices/light/{val}', [DevicesController::class, 'light']);
```

Вот функция в контроллере

```
public function light($val)
    {
        $let = DB::table('devices')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->update(['value' => $val]);
        return $let;
    }
```

И вот вызываемая функция во vue js

```
async light(val) {
            this.loading = true;
            let res = await fc("devices/light/"+val, "POST");
            console.log(val);
            console.log(res);
            this.loading = false;
        }
```

Скажите пожалуйста кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, все пути прописаны правильно и в postman этот запрос работает идеально

Функция fc()

```
async function fc(url, method, data, bearer = true, formData = false) {
    let fetchData = {
        method: method,
        headers: {},
    };
    if (method != "GET" && !formData) {
        fetchData['headers']['Content-Type'] = "application/json";
        fetchData['body'] = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
    if (bearer)
        fetchData['headers']['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + localStorage.token;
    let res = await fetch("http://brainapi/api/" + url, fetchData);
    let resJson = {};
    if (res.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json')
        resJson = await res.json();
    return {
        status: res.status,
        json: resJson,
    };
}
```

Comment: Тут `fc("devices/light/"+val, "POST");` случаем `api` дописать не надо?

Comment: нет, оно прописано в другой переменной, посмотрите я там написал что выводит в консоль

Comment: Может приложите код функции `fc()`? Потому что так-то Вы нам не сам `fetch()` показываете.

Comment: добавил функцию

Comment: все решил, всем спасибо)

Comment: @Артём было бы неплохо написать решение в ответы, вдруг у кого-то тоже возникнет такая проблема